# Using sed to move part of filename

Tags: sed, rename

I have some music files which are named as 'track name [artist]'.

I want them to be  '[artist] trackname', and so need to move the square brackets and what's in them to the start of the file.

I've just discovered sed, but don't have the brains to understand how to use it to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using sed

There are many ways to do this.  If you want to do this while learning `sed`, then try:

```
$ filename='track name [artist].mp3'
$ newname=$(echo "$filename" | sed -E 's/(.*[^[:space:]])[[:space:]]*[[](.*)[]]/[\2] \1/')
$ echo "$newname"
[artist] track name.mp3
```

The sed substitution command has the form `s/old/new/` where `old` is a regular expression.  In this case `old` consists of parts:

1. `(.*[^[:space:]])` captures the track name.  Because this regex is surrounded by parens, the track name is saved in a group.  The `.*` part matches anything.  The `[^[:space:]]` matches any non-whitespace.  By putting `[^[:space:]]` at the end, we have assured that this captures the track name but not the white space after it.
2. `[[:space:]]*[[]` matches spaces, if any, that follow the track name and the `[` that follows them.  Because `[` is a sed-active character, we have to escape it some way.  Here, we escape it by placing it in square brackets as `[[]`.
3. `(.*)[]]` matches text up to the final `]` in the file name.  The parens here cause the artist name to be captured as a second group.

The `new` part of the substitution command is `[\2] \1`.  This puts the second group `\2` (the artist name) first and first group `\1` (the track name) second.

#### Shortcut for renaming files

If your goal is to rename files, I would recommend the `rename` command from the perl package (sometimes called `prename`):

```
$ ls *mp3
track name [artist].mp3
$ prename 's/(.*[^[:space:]])[[:space:]]*[[](.*)[]]/[$2] $1/' *.mp3
$ ls *mp3
[artist] track name.mp3
```

`prename` uses a perl substitution command which is very similar to sed's but references the captured groups not as `\1` and `\2` but as `$1` and `$2`.

NOTE: Some linuxes install a different `rename` utility that is *incompatible* and will not work as above.

Comment: @ John1024 ... thanks. For whatever reason, I've only today received notification of your reply, which I've tried to accept/upvote. This is added as an answer because it won't accept a comment.

Comment: looks like the question was posted as an unregistered account. Use the contact us link to request a merger.

Comment: @gulliver I'm glad it helped, even if you got the notice so many months late.  I hope that, following JourneymanGeek's suggestion, you can get your account straightened out.  You won't be able to upvote until you get 15 points of rep but, for your own questions, you will certainly be able to accept an answer.  When your account gets squared away, let me know and I'll upvote your question.